# Show that two norms $||f||_1=(∫_0^1 |f(x)|^2/(x^{1/2})dx)^{1/2}$ and $||f||_2=(∫_0^1 |f(x)|^3/(x^{1/2})dx)^{1/3}$ are equivalent (or not) in $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

I also tried to evaluate somehow and $f_n$ so that it doesn't diverge in the square, and it does diverge in the cube, it won't work, and because it goes to infinity and from such functions as
$f_n(t):= n^2 t - 2n$ if $0 \le t \le n^{-1}; 0 $ if $ n^{-1} \le t, $
they always go to infinity together, and Helder doesn't give much, and after triying using third norm does not work, $||f||_0=∫_0^1|f|dx$ will not be equivalent to these two, and in general the space will not be complete relative to those norms.

I found that it could rather less complicated, but i have no idea why i can not have inequality from bottom to prove

$||f||_1=(∫_0^1 |f(x)|^2/(x^{1/2})dx)^{1/2} \le (∫_0^1 1/(x^{1/2})dx)^{1/2} (∫_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2} \le 2^{1/2} ∫_0^1 |f(x)|dx \le 2^{1/2} max{|f|},$

$||f||_2=(∫_0^1 |f(x)|^3/(x^{1/2})dx)^{1/3} \le (∫_0^1 1/(x^{1/2})dx)^{1/3} (∫_0^1 |f(x)|^3 dx)^{1/3} \le 2^{1/3} ∫_0^1 |f(x)|dx \le 2^{1/3} max{|f|},$

hence $||f||_1 \sim ||f||_2$

Am i wrong? Could you please advice me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: why people downvoting my question

Comment: you need to reformat the question properly using mathjax notations. Its almost unreadable in current form. Avoid using picture links.

Comment: am i succeeded in reformatting or it steel bad?

Comment: Good reformatting. Besides, do you know that there is a strong form of equivalence : there exist constants $p,q$ such that for all $x$, $ \ p \|x\|_1 \le \|x\|_2 \le q \|x\|_1$ ? Is it this one you are thinking to ?

Comment: I'm triying to make something like that inequation, but I cannot reach it for my $||f||_1$ and $||f||_2$, so i thought they whould be inequivalent. although C[0,1] whould not be complete relative to $||f||_1$ or $||f||_2$, can i use that inequation to prove equality of norms if space is not complete relative to them?

Comment: But i cannot find  $f_n: ||f_n||_1 \to 0$ and $||f_n||_2 \to infinity,$ $n \to infinity$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider, for every $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x\in[0,1]:$
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1n-x&\text{if }x\le\frac1n\\0&\text{if }x\ge\frac1n.\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{align}{\|f_n\|_1}^2&=\int_0^{1/n}\left(x^{3/2}-\frac2nx^{1/2}+\frac1{n^2}x^{-1/2}\right)dx\\&=\left[\frac25x^{5/2}-\frac4{3n}x^{3/2}+\frac2{n^2}x^{1/2}\right]_0^{1/n}\\&=\left(\frac25-\frac43+2\right)n^{-5/2}\\&=\frac{16}{15}n^{-5/2}
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}{\|f_n\|_2}^3&=\int_0^{1/n}\left(-x^{5/2}+\frac3nx^{3/2}-\frac3{n^2}x^{1/2}+\frac1{n^3}x^{-1/2}\right)dx\\&=\left[-\frac27x^{7/2}+\frac6{5n}x^{5/2}-\frac2{n^2}x^{3/2}+\frac2{n^3}x^{1/2}\right]_0^{1/n}\\&=\left(-\frac27+\frac65-2+2\right)n^{-7/2}\\&=\frac{32}{35}n^{-7/2}
\end{align}$$
Therefore, as $n\to\infty,$
$$\frac{\|f_n\|_2}{\|f_n\|_1}=C\frac{n^{-7/6}}{n^{-5/4}}=Cn^{1/12}\to+\infty.$$
This proves that the two norms are not equivalent.

On the other hand, by Hölder inequality, for every $f\in C([0,1]),$
$$\|f\|_1=\|x^{-1/4}f\|_{L^2}\le\|x^{-1/6}f\|_{L^3}\|x^{-1/12}\|_{L^6}=2^{1/6}\|f\|_2.$$